# Asserting a collection of objects is a part of another collection of objects of the same type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to use `.BeSubsetOf()` from Fluent Assertions to ensure that one collection of objects is a subset of another, bigger collection of objects of the same type, but the assertion always fails.

Example code:

```
    var expected = new[]
    {
        new Campus
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Campus 1"
        },

        new Campus
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Campus 2"
        },

        new Campus
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Campus 3"
        }
    };

    var actual = new[]
    {
        new Campus
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Campus 1"
        },

        new Campus
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Campus 2"
        }
    };

    actual.Should().BeSubsetOf(expected);
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: This is probably because it's defaulting to reference equality. There should be an overload to do your own comparison. https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That is happening because `BeSubsetOf` use the object's
> `.Equals` method for comparison.

One option is to override `.Equals` method of the type you are comparing.

Second alternative can be to verify one object at the time

```
foreach (var campus in actual)
{
   expected.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(campus);
}
```

Comment: foreach version works great, thanks!